# BinaryTree will not assign newly created node

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The problem lies in the insert method with two parameters.
The function, insert(char letter, string code), calls insert(TreeNode *node, char letter, char code). However it does not assign the left or right child as the node. The insert method with three parameters should create a new node. Then this node should be assigned as either a left or a right child.

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

BinaryTree::BinaryTree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() {
    empty_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::empty_tree(TreeNode *node) {
    if (root) {
        if (node->left) {
            return empty_tree(node->left);
        }
        if (node->right) {
            return empty_tree(node->right);
        }
        delete node;
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(char letter, string code) {
    TreeNode *node = root;
    TreeNode *temp = nullptr;
    if (node) {
        for (string::size_type i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
            //temp = node;
            if (code[i] == '.') {
                if (node->left) {
                    node = node->left;
                }
                else {
                    insert(temp, letter, code[i]);
                    node->left = temp;

                }
            }
            else {
                if (node->right) {
                    node = node->right;
                }
                else {
                    return insert(temp, letter, code[i]);
                    node->right = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*else {
        return insert();
    }*/
}

void BinaryTree::insert() {
    if (!root) {
        root= new TreeNode();
        root->letter = '*';
        root->left = nullptr;
        root->right = nullptr;
        root->code = "*";
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *node, char letter, char code) {
    if (!node) {
        node = new TreeNode();
        node->letter = letter;
        node->left = nullptr;
        node->right = nullptr;
        node->code += code;
    }
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree() {
    return print_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree(TreeNode *tree) {
    if (tree) {
        if (tree->left) {
            print_tree(tree->left);
        }
        if (tree->right) {
            print_tree(tree->right);
        }
        cout << "Node is " << tree->letter << " and in Morse Code is " << tree->code << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Below is the file containing main. The morse-code.txt file just has the alphabet letters in order from a to z. Each line has one letter, followed by a space, followed by the morse code.

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::string code;
    std::ifstream infile;
    char letter;
    BinaryTree tree;;

    infile.open("morse-code.txt");
    if (!infile) {
        std::cout << "File unable to open" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "morse-code.txt\n\n";
        tree.insert();
        while (std::getline(infile, code)) {
            tree.insert(code[0], code.substr(2, code.length()-2));
            cout << code << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n******Tree Representation******\n\n";
        tree.print_tree();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

text file

```
a .-
b -...
c -.-.
d -..
e .
f ..-.
g --.
h ....
i ..
j .---
k -.-
l -.--
m --
n -.
o ---
p .--.
q --.-
r .-.
s ...
t -
u ..-
v ...-
w .--
x -..-
y -.--
z --..
```

tree.h

```
#ifndef _TREE_H
#define _TREE_H

//#include <iostream>
//#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class BinaryTree {
private:
    struct TreeNode {
        char letter;
        string code;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;
    }; TreeNode *root;

public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    void insert();
    void insert(TreeNode *new_node, char letter, char code);
    void insert(char letter, string code);
    void empty_tree(TreeNode *node);
    void print_tree(TreeNode *node);
    void print_tree();
};
#endif
```

Comment: You may as well add `tree.h` and `morse-code.txt` to your question.

Comment: Unless you're required to use a binary tree (e.g., because this is a school assignment) this is a case where an array/vector is *strongly* preferred over a tree. The tree will almost always be slower and use more memory, and in this case provides no real benefit.

Comment: Yes, binary tree is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem was in my tree_driver.cpp file. Most of the problems contained in that file were in the insert function with two parameters. Below is the working code.

tree_driver.cpp

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

BinaryTree::BinaryTree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() {
    empty_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::empty_tree(TreeNode *node) {
    if (!node) {
        if (node->left) {
            empty_tree(node->left);
        }
        if (node->right) {
            empty_tree(node->right);
        }
        delete node;
    }
}

//The following member function contains the most alterations
void BinaryTree::insert(char letter, string code) {
    if (!root) {
        insert(root, letter, code, true);
    }
    else {
        TreeNode *node = root;
        for (string::size_type i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
            if (code[i] == '.') {
                if (!node->left) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        insert(node->left, letter, code.substr(0, i + 1), true);
                    }
                    else {
                        insert(node->left, letter, code.substr(0, i + 1), false);
                    }
                }
                node = node->left;
                if (node->left) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        node->letter = letter;
                    }
                }
                if (!node->left) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        node->letter = letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (code[i] == '-') {
                if (!node->right) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        insert(node->right, letter, code.substr(0, i + 1), true);
                    }
                    else {
                        insert(node->right, letter, code.substr(0, i + 1), false);
                    }
                }
                node = node->right;
                if (node->right) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        node->letter = letter;
                    }
                }
                if (!node->right) {
                    if (i == code.length() - 1) {
                        node->letter = letter;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&node, char letter, string code, bool last) {
    if (last) {
            node = new TreeNode();
            node->letter = letter;
            node->right = nullptr;
            node->left = nullptr;
            node->code = code;
    }
    if (!last) {
            node = new TreeNode();
            node->letter = '\0';
            node->right = nullptr;
            node->left = nullptr;
            node->code = code;
    }
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree() {
    print_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree(TreeNode *tree) {
    if (tree) {
        if (tree->left) {
            print_tree(tree->left);
        }
        cout << "Node is " << tree->letter << " and in Morse Code is " << tree->code << endl << endl;
        if (tree->right) {
            print_tree(tree->right);
        }
    }
}
```

tree_tester.

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::string code_main;
    std::ifstream infile;
    BinaryTree tree;;

    infile.open("morse-code.txt");
    if (!infile) {
        std::cout << "File unable to open" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "morse-code.txt\n\n";
        tree.insert('0', "*");
        while (std::getline(infile, code_main)) {
            tree.insert(code_main[0], code_main.substr(2, code_main.length()-2));
            cout << code_main << endl;
        }
        infile.close();
        cout << "\n******Tree Representation******\n\n";
        tree.print_tree();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

tree.h

```
#ifndef _TREE_H
#define _TREE_H

#include <string>

using std::string;

class BinaryTree {
private:
    struct TreeNode {
        string letter;
        string code;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;
    }; TreeNode *root;

public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    /*void insert();*/
    void insert(TreeNode *&new_node, char letter, string code, bool last);
    void insert(char letter, string code);
    void empty_tree(TreeNode *node);
    void print_tree();
    void print_tree(TreeNode *node);
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that insert isn't the only problems you have with your code. Your empty_tree is incorrect (will not free all of the memory, since you return prematurely. The specific part of the code you have wrong is the following line of your code: "return insert(temp, letter, code[i]);"
The rest of your code looks fine.

It should look something like this instead:

```
void BinaryTree::empty_tree(TreeNode *node) {
    if (!node) return;
    delete node;
    empty_tree(node->left );
    empty_tree(node->right);
    /* See Jerry's solution below. */
}

void BinaryTree::insert(char letter, string code) {
    TreeNode *node = root;
    if (!root) /* do something*/;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
        if (code[i] == '.') {
            if (node->left)
                insert(&node->left, letter, code[i]);
            node = node->left;
        }
        else {
            if (!node->right)
                insert(&node->right, letter, code[i]);
            node = node->right
        }
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode **node, char letter, string code) {
    *node = new TreeNode();
    (*node)->letter = letter;
    (*node)->left = nullptr;
    (*node)->right = nullptr;
    (*node)->code = code;
}
```

In tree.h:

```
typedef struct _TreeNode {
    char letter;
    string code;
    struct _TreeNode *left;
    struct _TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode; TreeNode *root;
```

I *compiled the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _TreeNode {
    char letter;
    string code;
    struct _TreeNode *left;
    struct _TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

class BinaryTree {
private:
    TreeNode *root;
public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    void insert();
    void insert(TreeNode **new_node, char letter, string code);
    void insert(char letter, string code);
    void empty_tree(TreeNode *node);
    void print_tree(TreeNode *node);
    void print_tree();
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() {
    empty_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::empty_tree(TreeNode *node) {
    if (!node) return;
    delete node;
    empty_tree(node->left );
    empty_tree(node->right);
}

void BinaryTree::insert(char letter, string code) {
    TreeNode *node = root;
    if (!root) insert();
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
        if (code[i] == '.') {
            if (!node->left)
                insert(&node->left, letter, code.substr(0,i));
            node = node->left;
        } else {
            if (!node->right)
                insert(&node->right, letter, code.substr(0,i));
            node = node->right;
        }
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert() {
    root = new TreeNode();
    root->letter = '*';
    root->left = nullptr;
    root->right = nullptr;
    root->code = "*";
}

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode **node, char letter, string code) {
    *node = new TreeNode();
    (*node)->letter = letter;
    (*node)->left = nullptr;
    (*node)->right = nullptr;
    (*node)->code = code;
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree() {
    return print_tree(root);
}

void BinaryTree::print_tree(TreeNode *tree) {
    if (tree) {
        if (tree->left ) print_tree(tree->left );
        cout << "Node is " << tree->letter << " and in Morse Code is "
             << tree->code << endl << endl;
        if (tree->right) print_tree(tree->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    string code;
    ifstream infile;
    char letter;
    BinaryTree tree;

    infile.open("morse-code.txt");
    if (!infile) {
        cout << "File unable to open" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "morse-code.txt\n\n";
        tree.insert();
        while (std::getline(infile, code)) {
            tree.insert(code[0], code.substr(2, code.length()-2));
            cout << code << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n******Tree Representation******\n\n";
        tree.print_tree();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `empty_tree` can be further simplified to: `if (!node) return; empty_tree(node->left); empty_tree(node->right); delete node;`

Comment: If you compare your code with the one I provided, the major edits are your premature return statements which caused your code to not fully complete the iterative step, and the else statements, where you forgot to nullify your temp node (because if it is not null, then your insert(TreeNode*,char,char); would not actually create a new node for temp, causing your program to just fill the tree with duplicate data. Additionally, you forgot to continue the step with node = node->left/right like you did in the 'if' part of the statements.

Comment: For some reason temp is still referenced as null, so when I have node->left = temp this makes node = nullptr. Now at the next iteration when char[i] = '-', node being null causes an exception.

Comment: hmm, I don't really know what that would happen. Perhaps it maybe because of the way that TreeNode is being initialized. I know that in C, you need to use 'struct TreeNode' every time you reference it, instead of just TreeNode. I'll add this to the answer, and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: @RahulManne: Thank you for the help, still not working, so I will just keep working on it until it does.